# Configure columns when importing CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin to import a CSV file into a MySQL database, the file contains a column that has 672 binary numbers, if I import that without checking the box `The first line of the file contains the table column names (if this is unchecked, the first line will become part of the data)` everything goes in as VARCHAR columns and life is good.
[image]
If I check that box however, it tries to insert that column as a BIGINT and it fails because the maximum value for that is 255.

[image]

How can I modify the fields in the CSV file or while importing to MySQL to say consider every column is a varchar?

**EDIT**
Here's a subset of the data I'm trying to import. Save that into a CSV file:

```
ZomatoURL,PhoneNumber,More Info,Claimed,Booking,Hours2,RestaurantName,HoursMon,HoursTue,HoursWed,HoursThu,HoursFri,HoursSat,HoursSun
https://www.zomato.com/sydney/koi-dessert-bar-chippendale,02 9212 1230,More Info  Takeaway Available Wheelchair Accessible No Alcohol Available Gluten Free Options Desserts and Bakes Kid Friendly Vegetarian Friendly,Report Error Claim this listing,,MonClosedTue10 AM to 10 PMWed10 AM to 10 PMThu10 AM to 10 PMFri10 AM to 10 PMSat10 AM to 10 PMSun10 AM to 10 PM,KOI Dessert Bar,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
https://www.zomato.com/sydney/kobe-wagyu-yakiniku-cbd,02 9283 2268,More Info  No Alcohol Available Sake Buffet,Claimed listing?,Table booking recommended,"Mon  12 Noon to 2:30 PM, 5:30 PM to 10:30 PM Tue 12 Noon to 2:30 PM, 5:30 PM to 10:30 PM Wed 12 Noon to 2:30 PM, 5:30 PM to 10:30 PM Thu 12 Noon to 2:30 PM, 5:30 PM to 10:30 PM Fri 12 Noon to 2:30 PM, 5 PM to 11:30 PM Sat    12 Noon to 11:30 PM Sun 12 Noon to 10:30 PM",Kobe Wagyu Yakiniku,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111100000000000011111111111111111111000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000111111111111111111110000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000111111111111111111110000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000111111111111111111110000000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111000000000011111111111111111111111111000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000,111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
https://www.zomato.com/sydney/home-thai-cbd,02 9261 5058,More Info  Takeaway Available BYO BYOW Vegetarian Friendly,Report Error Claim this listing,,Mon    11 AM to 11 PM Tue  11 AM to 11 PM Wed  11 AM to 11 PM Thu  11 AM to 11 PM Fri  11 AM to 11 PM Sat  11 AM to 11 PM Sun  11 AM to 11 PM,Home Thai,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000,100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: Are you trying to import to an existing table or letting phpMyAdmin create the table during import? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch i'm letting phpMyAdmin create a table during import and the version I'm using is 4.0.10.18

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that problem here; when i try it works as expected. Can you reproduce it on the demo server at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net ? Your phpMyAdmin version is rather old, you should upgrade if possible to the more modern version 4.7 if your PHP and MySQL versions allow that. Can you reduce your problematic CSV file to a few lines that you could post here for me to try?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I'll try upgrading the phpmyadmin on a different server so it wouldn't affect my colleagues. I was able to reproduce the issue on demo.phpmyadmin.net and received a `#1264 - Out of range value for column 'HoursTue' at row 1` (check nick_test database). I've edited the question and added a subset of the data there, thanks for the help Isaac I appreciate it